# SQL Join two query results

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

First SQL Query (Total Memroy)

```
SELECT 
Nodes.NodeID AS NodeID,  Nodes.TotalMemory AS TotalMemory, Nodes.Caption AS NodeName
 FROM 
(Nodes INNER JOIN Volumes ON (Nodes.NodeID = Volumes.NodeID))
```

Second SQL Query (Number of CPU on nodes)

```
SELECT N.Caption, COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex)

FROM CPUMultiLoad_Detail CPU WITH(NOLOCK)

JOIN Nodes N ON CPU.NodeID = N.NodeID

GROUP BY
N.Caption
Order By
N.Caption
```

I want to join first query and second query so i have both Total memory and Number of CPU on node in same table. How do i join both query? we can use common key `Nodes.NodeID` to join but how?

Comment: Just a link - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/how-to-join-two-result-sets-to-query-on-output-came-from-two-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case just use a join and a CTE

```
WITH PartOne AS
(
  SELECT N.NodeID, COUNT(DISTINCT CPU.Index) as [Count]
  FROM CPUMultiLoad_Detail CPU WITH(NOLOCK)
  JOIN Nodes N ON CPU.NodeID = N.NodeID
  GROUP BY N.Caption
)
SELECT Nodes.NodeID 
       Nodes.TotalMemory , 
       Nodes.Caption AS NodeName,
       PartOne.[Count]
FROM Nodes 
INNER JOIN Volumes ON Nodes.NodeID = Volumes.NodeID
JOIN PartOne ON PartOne.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID
```

This particular case can also be done in one query like this:

```
SELECT Nodes.NodeID 
       Nodes.TotalMemory , 
       Nodes.Caption AS NodeName,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CPU.Index) OVER (PARTITION BY Nodes.Caption ORDER BY Nodes.Caption) AS [Count]
FROM Nodes 
JOIN Volumes ON Nodes.NodeID = Volumes.NodeID
JOIN CPUMultiLoad_Detail CPU ON  CPU.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID
```

Comment: In first query i am getting this error, I am using MS SQL management studio to run query : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon`

Comment: @Satish, just as it says, put a `;` before the `WITH`

Comment: And in second query it is saying `syntex error near keyword ORDER`

Comment: That did magic also i have fixed few fields which is `GROUP BY N.Caption` but i am getting few duplicate entries how do i remove them or short them

Comment: @Satish - sounds like a new question to me.  Maybe you have duplicate entries?

Comment: Anyway i will figure that out, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the same situation i used the Temp Table

SELECT ..... FROM.... INTO #Temp1

GO

SELECT ..... FROM.... INTO #Temp2

GO

SELECT ..... FROM #Temp1, #Temp2
WHERE #Temp1.NodeID = #Temp2.NodeID

Remember to Drop the Temp Tables like This:

DROP Table #Temp1
DROP Table #Temp2

Comment: You don't need to drop temp tables.

Comment: Yeah true, but is "Suggested" on huge Stored Procedure

Comment: Where is it suggested?

Comment: A Collegue expert on Sql Server. But I also find this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27309/why-does-delete-leave-a-lingering-effect-on-performance/27319#27319

Comment: Strange I don't see anything there about dropping tables, just about truncating and deleting rows.

Answer (score 0):

"With" comes in help to have a clean query:

```
    WITH CPUOnNodes AS (    
       SELECT N.NodeID, N.Caption, COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex)
       FROM CPUMultiLoad_Detail CPU WITH(NOLOCK)
       JOIN Nodes N ON CPU.NodeID = N.NodeID
       GROUP BY N.NodeID, N.Caption
       Order By N.Caption
    )
    SELECT N.NodeID, N.TotalMemory, N.Caption NodeName
    FROM Nodes N 
    INNER JOIN Volumes V ON N.NodeID = V.NodeID
    INNER JOIN CPUOnNodes C ON N.NodeID = C.NodeID
```

Comment: You are missing the count from CTE

Answer (score 0):

---

```
SELECT t1.col2,t2.col3 FROM (SELECT NodeID col1,TotalMemory col2,Caption col3 FROM Nodes)t1 join
(SELECT NodeID col1,Caption col2,COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex) col3 FROM CPUMultiLoad_Detail CPU WITH(NOLOCK) GROUP BY Caption Order By Caption)t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1
```